# How to notify other application in background that some action has happened in Android Pie?

Tags: android

I'm trying to do some operation on my service based on user input (say X) and I would like to notify other application that the action X has happened. So that the other apps are aware of what's going on in the system.

Possible approaches validated:

1. Broadcasting a message that action X has happened.
2. Starting a service within other app based on action X.

But (1) and (2) has limitations after Oreo that I need to specify explicitly the receiver name and for (2) I will not be able to start a background service. And the other limitation which I felt bad on broadcast is that it's taking my message in a queue and processing it one by one but my case is that I need to notify it immediately.

Note : I'm a system app and I live within system/priv-app space.